# Hibernate bidirectional @OneToMany mapping return Column 'xxx' cannot be null

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a problem with Hibernate bidirectional `@OneToMany` mapping.
This is my root entity:

```java
@Entity(name = "Proposta")
@Table(name = "PROPOSTA")
public class Proposta implements Serializable {
        
   private static final long serialVersionUID = -705828064150128352L;
        
   public Proposta() {
       super();
   }
            
   @Id
   @Column(name = "COD_PROPOSTA")
   private Integer codProposta; 
            
   @OneToMany(mappedBy="proposta", fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
   @Cascade({ CascadeType.ALL })
   private List<PropostaUL> listaPropostaUl;

}
```

This is my child entity:

```java
@Entity(name = "PropostaUL")
@Table(name = "PROPOSTA_UL")
public class PropostaUL {
        
   public PropostaUL() {
      super();
   }
    
   @Id
   @Column(name = "COD_FONDO_UE_UL")
   private String codFondoUeUl; 
        
   @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
   @JoinColumn(name = "COD_PROPOSTA")
   private Proposta proposta;

}
```

When I read the values of the two tables everything works properly; when I try to save it instead I have the following error

```
gen 05, 2021 10:14:03 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 1048, SQLState: 23000
gen 05, 2021 10:14:03 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: Column 'COD_PROPOSTA' cannot be null
gen 05, 2021 10:14:03 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.AbstractBatchImpl release
INFO: HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements
```

The save call it the following

```java
protected Object saveOrUpdate(Object obj, List<String> errorLog) {
   Transaction transaction = null;
   try {
      if (session == null || ! session.isOpen()) {
         session = HibernateFactory.getSessionFactory().openSession();
      } 
      transaction = session.beginTransaction();
      session.saveOrUpdate(obj);
      transaction.commit();
   } catch (HibernateException e) {
      obj = null;
      errorLog.add(e.getMessage());
   } finally {
      if (session != null) {
         session.close();
      } 
   }
   return obj;
}
```

I read other same problems in the forum but all the solutions suggested doesn't worked.
I checked this site too

https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetomany-association-with-jpa-and-hibernate/

and even if the case analyzed seems the same, and the configuration too, the problem persists. The value of `COD_PROPOSTA` in the root entity is provided and it is not `null`. Do you have any suggestion on how to solve the problem?

Comment: `when I try to save it` please show how you try to save it

Comment: Hi. I modify my original message and I added the save method. Thanks

Comment: hi i think you need to include the service or method that calls `saveOrUpdate`

Comment: The object that I have to save is a json object that is converted to an object via jackson library and here the COD_PROPOSTA is filled. I call the method that I included in the question and I pass it as parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for your answers.

I found the problem.

The object that I have to save is json object converted in Java object via Jackson library.

So I added @JsonManagedReference and @JsonBackReference to the objects and it works.

This is the right code

```
@Entity(name = "Proposta")
@Table(name = "PROPOSTA")
public class Proposta implements Serializable {
        
   private static final long serialVersionUID = -705828064150128352L;
        
   public Proposta() {
       super();
   }
            
   @Id
   @Column(name = "COD_PROPOSTA")
   private Integer codProposta; 
            
   @JsonManagedReference
   @OneToMany(mappedBy="proposta", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
   private List<PropostaUL> listaPropostaUl;

}
```

and the PropostaUL object

```
@Entity()
@Table(name = "PROPOSTA_UL")
public class PropostaUL {
    
    public PropostaUL() {
        super();
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = "COD_FONDO_UE_UL")
    private String codFondoUeUl;    
    
    @JsonBackReference
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "COD_PROPOSTA")
    private Proposta proposta;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The column "COD_PROPOSTA" and "COD_FONDO_UE_UL" marked as Id cannot be null and you are not giving any value to that property (unless you do it manually once created the object). To give an Id automatically you can add the annotation `@GeneratedValue` to `codProposta` and `codFondoUeUl`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunatelly. it doesn't work. The id values of the id column exists and are unique. I cheched it.

Comment: Can you show how are you creating your objects `Proposta` and `PropostaUL` and where you set the id's to those objects?

Comment: The object that I have to save is a json object that is converted to an object via jackson library and here the COD_PROPOSTA is filled.

Answer (score 0):

As it stated in the [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-one-to-many-bidirectional):

> Whenever a bidirectional association is formed, the application developer must make sure both sides are in-sync at all times.

So you should add `addPropostaUl()` and `removePropostaUl()` utility methods that synchronize both ends whenever a child element is added or removed:

```java
@Entity
public class Proposta implements Serializable {
    
   // ...
        
   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "proposta", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
   @Cascade(CascadeType.ALL)
   private List<PropostaUL> listaPropostaUl;
 
   public void addPropostaUl(PropostaUL propostaUl) {
      listaPropostaUl.add(propostaUl);
      propostaUl.setProposta(this);
   }

   public void removePropostaUl(PropostaUL propostaUl) {
      listaPropostaUl.remove(propostaUl);
      propostaUl.setProposta(null);
   }
}
```

and then use only these methods when you want modify this association.

Example (adding new `PropostaUL` to the existent `Proposta`):

```java
Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();

Proposta proposta = session.load(Proposta.class, propostaId);
PropostaUL newPropostaUL = new PropostaUL();
// ...
proposta.addPropostaUl(newPropostaUL);
session.saveOrUpdate(proposta);

transaction.commit();
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer. I tried it but it doesn't work. In my project I use the hibernate version 4.3.5.Final. The object that I have to save is a json object that is converted to an object via jackson library and here the COD_PROPOSTA is filled.

Comment: Yes, direct saving incoming json as entities lead to the problems like this one. That is why it is general practice to keep DTOs related to the client-server API and orm entities separately.